# Find Out the TrustLevel of a Running Process

Tags: windows, process, elevation

I can run processes with a specific `TrustLevel` like this:

```
RunAs /TrustLevel:0x20000 process.exe
```

But, how do I find out the `TrustLevel` of a process that is already running? Is there any app available which can show this info?

Answer (score 2):

The trustlevel parameter is a legacy thing that is related to software restriction policies (SRP) in Group Policy. It allowed an administrator to run a otherwise blocked program.

SRP used to have three levels: restricted, unrestricted and "default user". The "default user" setting was retired with Windows Vista, so this parameter isn't useful anymore, and there's only one trustlevel available anymore.

Please note that the trustlevel does not relate to UAC integrity levels.

Comment: I believe that you are wrong. The `RunAs` tool doesn't show all the available `TrustLevel`s when requested using the `ShowTrustLevels` argument. There are at least four `TrustLevel`s available in Windows Vista+ : `Untrusted = 0x1000, Constrained = 0x10000, NormalUser = 0x20000, FullyTrusted = 0x40000`. You can verify this by running any app that shows you whether it has admin rights or not using `RunAs` and specifying the different `TrustLevel`s I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Check this for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/a/287072/864101 . Also programmers can specify 3 `TrustLevels` in the manifest file: `asInvoker, requireAdministrator, highestAvailable`

Comment: Sounds like I'm indeed partially wrong - there's no "clear" explanation for the trustlevel parameter. But anyway, I still do believe that it is related (or at least only partially related) to the UAC privilege levels (low, medium, high, system) or the application manifest requestedexecutionlevel. If you want to get the integrity label of a process, you have to enumerate its DACL.

Comment: The manifest entry requestedExecutionLevel specifies the Integrity Level the program is to run at. Prior to Windows 8 there were four levels used: System, High, Medium, Low. Process Explorer can be configured to show process integrity level.